# Spring Boot Transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions

guys! I don't really understand one thing with DB and Spring. Could you explain me why this is happened?
I have one method

> getByRegNumber(regNumber)

But after the first call, when I changed some field in DB tool(Data Grip, for example) for this row, another call return me the same entity, without changies.
For example:

```
 MessageLogDto byRegNumber1 = messageLogReadService.getByRegNumber(regNumber);
        String statusDoc1 = byRegNumber1.getStatusDoc();
//change statusDoc in DB
     MessageLogDto byRegNumber2 = messageLogReadService.getByRegNumber(regNumber);
            String statusDoc2 = byRegNumber2.getStatusDoc();
//change statusDoc in DB
     MessageLogDto byRegNumber3 = messageLogReadService.getByRegNumber(regNumber);
            String statusDoc3 = byRegNumber3.getStatusDoc();
```

In the end I have the same values for all three statusDoc.

The getByRegNumber(String regNumber) method is:

```
MessageLog entity = messagesLogRepository.findFirstByRegNumberAndTypeDoc(regNumber, BCM_01.ZVT.getName())
        .orElse(new MessageLog());
return mapper.toDto(entity);
```

Comment: Let me guess. Using JPA...

Comment: @M.Deinum yes. We use JPA, not clear hibernate

Comment: JPA uses caching, changing stuff directly in the database doesn't change the cached object.